# Delphi - How can I detect presence of Anti-Virus Software?

Tags: delphi, antivirus

When anti-virus software is running during the installation of my software certain components do not get installed correctly.  I always tell the users to turn it OFF first.  But, they forget and then I am racking my brains trying to figure out what went wrong.  Is there a Delphi function that anyone knows about that can detect whether AntiVirus software is running, so I can alert the user before installation starts?

Comment: Interesting problem - what kind of software are you writing?

Comment: If this is a recurring problem, I'd say the problem is probably your installer.  Note that because of Delphi's awesomeness at creating standalone exe's that dont need bloated runtimes, a lot of virii and malware is written in it.  So its pretty frequent that anti-virus software fingerprints some part of a virus thats also found in other delphi programs.  Simply turning your anti-virus off isnt going to help - it'd just interfere as soon as it was turned back on.

Comment: @GrandmasterB: ...instead of relying on bloated runtimes, delphi produces über-bloated individual executables - which is of course a lot more awesome than a single big runtime and tiny individual executables.

Comment: @snemarch: Not as bloated as you might think.  Delphi's smartlinker is able to cut out the parts of the runtime libraries that the executable doesn't need, which keeps their size down.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: how bad is it these days? back when I used Delphi, I recall statically linked VCL executables were something like 2meg apiece.

Comment: snemarch: contrary to popular opinion, separate runtimes don't save that much, usually because there are small stub, versioning and resolving code added to the main binary too. You often need more than a hand full of binaries to break even (since you need to compensate for unused code in the runtime too), and except for the binaries of the OS and a few very large suites, usually there are not that much binaries on a system due to that the runtime libs are versioned too.

Comment: snemarch: older delphi's basically can generate 400k VCL apps. Nowdays closer to a 1MB. Can become bigger with apps that try to use all components though. Maybe you had debugcode in binary on (e.g. for a system to phone hoem tracebacks)

Answer (score 3):

Since XPsp2, there is the security center that registers if there is a known antivirus.

Afaik this functions over the WMI api, which can be accessed via Winapi. (and Jedi has headers for it).

I've found some VBScript here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/05/12/how-to-get-antivirus-information-with-wmi-vbscript.aspx

Another tip: try to communicate to your users in *any* way possible to turn off heuristic scans as much as possible. These are typically the cause of false positives, and it can be an easier message to bring than killing the antivirus all together.

Comment: Make sure you read the comments, because that exact piece of code won't work as of Vista SP1 - they removed the namespace you need.

Comment: There are alternatives in the comments too. Non of them is pretty, but this whole situation isn't. (as I already said, installed and "on" are also different things)

Comment: I must openly admit that I downvoted it. It's a terrible, terrible idea to bring users to reduce the amount of protection their antivirus offers. Remember: 100 false positives are still better than one false negative, and usually, heuristics are *good*.

Comment: Heuristics are largely to give consumers the feeling that the antivirus work and they spend their money right. The security value is doubtful, and the risk that users conflate signature based and heuristic real . Many corporate editions have no or only the most secure heuristics enabled

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote on my blog a article, which tell you how to detect the presence of the antivirus software in the Windows Desktop editions (XP, Vista and 7).

[`Getting the installed Antivirus, AntiSpyware and Firewall software using Delphi and the WMI`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/getting-the-installed-antivirus-antispyware-and-firewall-software-using-delphi-and-the-wmi/)

Answer (score 1):

> certain components do not get installed correctly

Explain what components you're installing, how you're installing those components, and how their installation is failing, and it will be easier to recommend a solution.  Also, are you using an installer product, or your own installation code?  If it's your own installer, or if you can automatically run your own code after the installer, you can do your own programmatic check to confirm your install is 100% OK, and if not then report what failed and remind the user to turn off antivirus stuff and retry the install.

Answer (score 1):

I see that this is an "old" question, but... 
i found it
[Retreive Antivirus Information using WMI](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/retreiveantivirusinformationusingwmi)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

We've had success by checking the running processes for any process that we've determined before-hand is an AV program. (You can enumerate a list of processes using some simple code that you can find by googling something List Running Processes Delphi)

If we find one, we tell the user and refuse to continue...

To build our list of processes that we know are AV, we install trial versions of the AV programs and then look at the list of processes (either in the task manager, or using our enumerate processes code.)  It's not to hard to spot them... and you can shut the AV programs down and see if the processes you identify go away. (Process Explorer is helpful: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

For example, some of the processes we currently look for include MCShield (McCaffe), NPROTECT (Norton), PCCNTMON (Trend Micro), etc.

Obviously this won't catch ALL AV programs, but if you do the above with the major vendors (Norton, McCaffe, Trend Micro, ZA, etc.) you'll have a large percentage of the AV programs in the field covered.

One thing that is nice about this is that it's easy to implement and doesn't require any really low level Windows API calls, except to enumerate the currently running processes...

Comment: Pretty darn fragile - you'd be better off *always* showing a splash screen (that *doesn't* look like a EULA or whatever) telling the users that running antivirus software could be problematic during install.